# The position of the word in a phrase

Tags: word-order

Look at the sentence, please:

> She reminded me of a sonatina by an old Italian composer with its wistfulness in which there is yet an urbane flippancy and its light rippling gaiety in which **echoes still** the trembling of a sigh
>
> (Source: Somerset Maugham, *Cakes and Ale; or, The Skeleton in the Cupboard*).

I don't understand why the word ‘still’ is placed after the verb ‘echoes’.

**One guess**: is it an inversion? Instead of ‘in which the trembling of a sigh still echoes’ we have this order. Does it mean that in such case the words ‘still’ and ‘echoes’ go to the beginning of the phrase *and change their places*?

Thanks!

Comment: This might sound hypocritical coming from me, but I don't think every answer needs a full, in-depth explanation ;)

Comment: @SamBC:  Maybe so, but (with some justification, I fully accept) the mods sometimes get a bit ticked off with me for *commenting* rather than posting an actual *Answer.*

Answer (score 3):

It's called [Stylistic Inversion](http://repository.seikei.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/10928/799/1/eibun-20_69-79.pdf). Just my opinion, but I think in your specific case the primary effect (apart from making the text more overtly "poetic") is to slightly "amplify" the adverb ***still***. Because it's not where we'd normally expect it (before the verb ***echoes***), we notice it more, and thus we're more aware of the meaning it imparts. Basically, it makes the reader pay closer attention, which is exactly what the author wants.

Note that there's no particular "rule" saying that just because ***still echoes*** has been "inverted", this should affect whether the *subject + verb* *(**the trembling of a sigh + echoes**)* is inverted. Or vice-versa. All 3 permutations (*adverb after verb, verb before subject,* or ***both***) are perfectly valid.

Also note that the simplest "Subject + Verb" inverted form is normally associated with ***ordinary questions*** rather than "poetic / literary style". That's to say ***Echoes still the trembling of a sigh?*** as a standalone utterance is a credible (albeit somewhat ["highfalutin"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/highfalutin)) question. But in practice we'd probably introduce "do-support" there, and ask ***Does the trembling of a sigh still echo?***

Comment: So then in which cases would be such question applicable: *Echoes still the trembling of a sigh?*

Comment: Definitely in the case of ***poetry*** - for example, [*Stands the Church clock at ten to three? \ And is there honey still for tea?*](https://www.bartleby.com/232/701.html) But in ordinary conversation the first question would normally feature do-support *(Does the Church clock stand at ten to three?)*, and the second would use the more "natural" sequence *Is there still honey for tea?*

Comment: And Fumblefingers, can you help me some more? In the next paragraph there is such phrase in brackets: *sometimes she looked like the exqisite statue of Psyche in the museum at Naples (it's about Rosie)*. Why ***at*** Naples, not *in*?

Comment: That's probably just because the text is almost a century old, and "default, preferred" usages change over time. It's not *wrong* to use ***at*** there - just that we'd be much more likely to use ***in*** today.